# Rails includes categories and sub-categories model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How i can include categories("parent") and subcategories("children") to get rid of N+1 query

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id

  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :articles, through: :article_categories

  scope :roots, -> { where(parent_id: 0) }
  scope :children, -> { where.not(parent_id: 0) }
end
```

Categories with parent_id 0 are "Category/Parent"

Categories with parent_id != 0 are "Subcategories/Children"

I declare instance in controller:

```
@articles = articles.includes(:categories)
```

In view:

```
@articles.each do |article|
  article.categories.roots #N+1 query solved using "includes(:categories)"
  article.categories.children.first  #N+1 query need to solve
  ..............
```

Problem is that every new cycle causes a new request to database because of article.categories.children.first

N+1 request is:

```
Category Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "article_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "article_categories"."category_id" WHERE "article_categories"."article_id" = $1 AND ("categories"."parent_id" != $2) ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["article_id", 450], ["parent_id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I need to include "parent/Categories"

also include "children/Subcategories" to get rid of N+1 query from ..."children.first"

More details:

```
articles.includes(:categories) =>

Article Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."customer_type" = $1 AND "articles"."aasm_state" IN ('published', 'unpublished') ORDER BY "articles"."title" ASC  [["customer_type", 0]]
ArticleCategory Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "article_categories".* FROM "article_categories" WHERE "article_categories"."article_id" IN (1, 2, ...)
Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 15, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to get rid from N+1 problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to preload article's children categories, you should define this association in `Article` model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_categories

  # '-> { children }' executes 'children' scope defined in 'Category' model
  has_many :children_categories, -> { children }, through: :article_categories, source: :category, class_name: "Category"
end
```

Now you can preload and fetch children categories using this association:

```
# in controller
@articles = articles.includes(:children_categories)

# in view
@articles.each do |article|
  article.children_categories.first
```

**Edit**

You might also want to add `default_scope` to category model to always fetch only children categories:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { children }
end
```

If you do this, you will not have to add `-> { children }` condition to associations.

Comment: "children_categories" is generating wrong sql. Article.last.children_categories.to_sql => "SELECT \"categories\".* FROM \"categories\" WHERE \"categories\".\"article_id\" = 450 AND (\"categories\".\"parent_id\" != 0)". Categories table doesn't have "article_id" attribute.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: No,  articles.includes(:children_categories).first => ArticleCategory Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "article_categories".* FROM "article_categories" WHERE ("categories"."parent_id" != $1) AND "article_categories"."article_id" = 1  [["parent_id", 0]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
LINE 1: ...le_categories".* FROM "article_categories" WHERE ("categorie...